# Parsing METAR webpage in python

Tags: python, parsing

I need to use METAR weather information in a python script. I found http://pypi.python.org/pypi/metar/1.4.0 which seems like it should work for what I need for current METARs. However, I also need to use archived weather information.

I found Navlost.eu, which seems to work well for what I need. For example,
http://www.navlost.eu/aero/metar/?icao=KBOS&dt0=2010-07-14+02%3A00%3A00&c=1&rt=metar

The python METAR module accesses a text file and parses that. How do I parse this webpage in a similar manner so that I am only grabbing the "KBOS 140154Z 15006KT 8SM -RA OVC034 23/22 A2994" text in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the raw `HTML` returned by the above link, you can see the METAR data nested between `<code>` tags:

```
<p><hr/><br/><code>KBOS 140154Z 15006KT 8SM -RA OVC034 23/22 A2994</code><br/><br/>
```

So use a Python regular expression to get at it:

```
import urllib2
import re

URL="http://www.navlost.eu/aero/metar/?icao=KBOS&dt0=2010-07-14+02%3A00%3A00&c=1&rt=metar"
f = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
data = f.read()

r = re.compile('<code>(.*)</code>', re.I | re.S | re.M)
print r.findall(data)[0]
```

The regular expression is found on the `re.compile` line, and the `(.*)` means that you're interested in all characters between the parentheses. The function `r.findall` returns all strings that match the expression, and `[0]` just gives the first one.

The following is the output:

```
KBOS 140154Z 15006KT 8SM -RA OVC034 23/22 A2994
```